# How to use LIKE query with table another table in SNOW API

Tags: servicenow-rest-api

I use TABLE API on SNOW to retrieve data. The problem is when I use LIKE query with the connected table's value, the API returns an empty array. I use below URL:

```
https://XXXXXX/api/now/table/task_sla?sysparm_query=sys_domainLIKEXXXX^has_breached=true^task.priorityIN4&sysparm_display_value=true^sla.nameLIKEResponse
```

If I delete *sla.nameLIKEResponse*, everything works fine. What can be the problem?

By the way, I can see data with the same filters on the UI.